# Get user review from Google map for my application

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api, mobile-application, location-based-service

I am new to mobile programming and this is my first time to use Android. I have to develop a location based services on mobile application.

I had done the step which able to allow user to login my application using (Google Oauth), get user location, get places nearby.

Now I want to show user review in the Map application from Google and user able to put their review for a place. How can I do that? I had read the document here. (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/index)
But still I am not sure where should I put it. Is there any documents for me to refer? A sample code will be big help for me...

Thanks in advance.